# Change time string to double

Tags: c#

So basically to change string time like "HH:MM:SS", I have to use TimeSpan.Parse. But my professor gave me the string form like this "MM:SS.FF". And surely I tried TimeSpan.Parse, but it threw some exception. So my question is what should i use in this case?

```
string aTime = "00:30.19";
```

Comment: What was the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use TimeSpan.TryParseExact instead:

```
TimeSpan interval;
string aTime = "00:30.19";
TimeSpan.TryParseExact(aTime , @"mm\:ss\.ff", null, out interval);
Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", aTime , interval.ToString("c"));
```

Output would be:

```
00:30.19 --> 00:00:30.1900000
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it tho

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to number manually. For example two low value digits for second, next two digits for minutes and so on.

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel. .NET guys have already coded and teste `TimeSpan.TryParseExact`